# Executing Insert Statements in Parallel in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure that executes 3 [insert/select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) statements into 3 different tables in Snowflake: ScheduleUnion, ScheduleUnion1, ScheduleUnion2. Now due to the time each statement takes to complete, i'd like to execute them in parallel to cut down on the overall execution time.To do this, I'm trying to make use of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in Javascript. I'm not going to post all of the insert statements here, but this sample is a good representation of how I'm tying to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure etl."JimTest" ()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS
$$

   async function runSQL(sqlarray) {

   snowflake.execute({ sqlText: sqlarray.sqltask } );
  }

   async function executeQuery() {

    sql1 = `INSERT into ScheduleUnion Select.....`
    sql2 = `INSERT into ScheduleUnion1 Select.....`
    sql3 = `INSERT into ScheduleUnion2 Select.....`

     const queries = [
        {sqltask: sql1},
        {sqltask: sql2},
        {sqltask: sql3}
    ];

    const sqlTasks = queries.map(runSQL);

    await Promise.all(sqlTasks); 
 }

  executeQuery();

  return 'done';
$$
```

However; I still see my insert statements running serially, one after the other:

[image]

Is there a [parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html) I'm missing, or something wrong with my Javascript?

Comment: I just ran your procedure with three selects, it ran parallel. I can think of two things, one if the insert is putting a transaction lock(which is unlikely since your tables are different) or if there is a queue overload happening means the entire warehouse resource is being used by the insert

Comment: Curious to hear if you got an answer? The execute() function is definitely blocking, but I don’t know javascript wise if putting it in an ash can function makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but better late than never:

Javascript parallelism within a single session is disabled in Snowflake.  Therefore, regardless of any attempts to force asynchronous thread launch from within a Snowflake stored procedure, all calls will execute sequentially.  In the OPs case, the .map() call will generate promises, and Promise.all() will wait for them all to resolve.  But the underlying engine will not behave in a multithreaded fashion, so it's all pointless.

In order to perform multi-threaded parallel operations, one must use an external client -- e.g. an ETL tool -- which launches independent session threads in parallel, via an external driver.  Both Talend and Matillion are readily capable of doing this.  I would recommend Matillion, as it is easier to use and has a simpler deployment architecture.

Answer (score 0):

A Snowflake warehouse is an MPP system that will schedule and execute commands in its queue based on the available processing capacity it has - you can't force it to run anything in parallel and it run will/may differ depending on resources available at run-time (i.e. what else is running).

If queries are not running fast enough then you have at least 2 Snowflake features available to you:

1. Increase the size of the warehouse you are using
2. Run each query with a different warehouse

Given that Snowflake allows all this to be scripted in SQL, at the start of your script you can increase the size of your warehouse (or create/start other warehouses) and at the end of your script you can reduce the size of your warehouse (or drop/stop other warehouses)

Comment: Did some more testing, this has nothing to do with available resources. I believe, and I can't prove this...but it appears you can only run one query at a time per session. I put all 3 insert statements into separate JDBC execute snaps in SnapLogic, and all 3 ran in parallel under different sessions in Snowflake. Did not resize the warehouse at all. Is there a way to initiate a new session for every separate thread in the proc?

Comment: It has nothing to do with sessions. [The API for Snowflake stored procedures is synchronous.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#synchronous-api)

Answer (score 0):

Tasks can be used to do stuff in parallel.

Because tasks can be set to run in overlapping mode:

```
ALLOW_OVERLAPPING_EXECUTION = TRUE | FALSE
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#overlapping-dag-runs
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#syntax

You can create a procedure that does the insert, then create a task that runs that procedure.
In your main function you can execute the task multiple times. The execute task command doesn't wait for the task to end, it runs in the background.

You can also monitor the tasks being executed by querying *.information_schema.task_history and wait for them to finish / fail / etc... by looping over the result and act accordingly or just exit the main procedure if all successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use SnowSQL [with the `results=False` configuration option](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config#results), which runs the queries asynchronously (without waiting for the result). *Caveat: this means you will need to check for the results separately.*

If you can get all of your queries into a SQL file, it could be as simple as this:

```bash
snowsql -o results=False -f queries.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [DAG of tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro#dag-of-tasks), and start the DAG via `EXECUTE TASK` (or schedule it).